# Minimalistic LT3080-1 current source

Tags: current-source, led-driver

I am trying to design a minimalistic current source to drive an LED from a lithium polymer battery and with a small number of components to minimize board space usage.
First I wanted to use the same type of current source shown in the datasheet of the LT3080 : 
[image: LT3080 current source]

then I noticed the LT3080-1 is the same but with a 25 mOhms resistor in the output of the functionnal diagram. So my question is :
Can I use LT3080-1 as current source with only the integrated 25 mOhms as output resistor?

It seems to work in LTSPICE with the following schematic with a 3.2 voltage source (not with 3 as on the picture) for a 65 mA current source (although there is a slight offset, which is okay for my application and can be accounted for anyway) :
[image: LT3080-1 current source]

But I am wondering if maybe there are imprecisions which will prevent repeatability of current accuracy in production? The current reference inside the component seems precise enough but I don't know the accuracy of the 25 mOhms resistor.

I want to use this component because of the low voltage drop (~0.3V) and the fact that I am driving an LED from a LIPO battery (4.2V max, 3.2V min) with a Vf= 2.9V. The 25 mOhm resistor also minimizes the voltage drop around the output resistor.

I don't want to use buck boost LED drivers because they are even more expensive and require more components.

Answer (score 1):

According to the passage on p.10 of [LT3080-1 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/30801fc.pdf),

> As shown in Figure 4, the two devices have internal ballast resistors,
>   which at full output current gives better than 90 percent equalized
>   sharing of the current.

This seems to imply that the tolerance of internal 25-mOhm ballast resistors is about +-5%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Flabou, what to elaborate? It might depend on their interpretation of "90% sharing equilization". My interpretation is: If one part gives 50% and another 50%, it is 100% equalized. If one part gives 45% and another 55%, , it would be 80% in my books. Therefore the equalization must be something like 47.5% and 52.5%, or 2.5/50 = 5%.